# How can I get the first column of a 300GB txt file?

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression, columns, large-files

let me first explain my problem in detail.
It's actually pretty simple. I have a huge .txt file, 300GB to be more preciese, and I would like to put all the distinct strings from the first column, that match my pattern into a different .txt file.

```
awk '{print $1}' file_name | grep -o '/ns/.*' | awk '!seen[$0]++' > test1.txt
```

This is what I've tried, and as far as I can see it works fine but the problem is that after some time I get the following error:

```
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
    FILENAME="file_name" FNR=117897124 NR=117897124
```

Any suggestions for parsing through a file this big?

Comment: What operating system?  Is GNU awk (`gawk`) available? https://groups.google.com/a/broadinstitute.org/forum/m/#!topic/xhmm-users/_Ocdzq06r1E

Comment: [cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934694/how-to-use-awk-and-grep-on-300gb-txt-file) is deemed a cardinal sin around here

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like `awk` hits a huge line which would result in 32767 or more fields. I cannot reproduce that with my `awk`, though:

```
> echo | awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<100000;i++) printf "%d ",i}; { print ""; }' >file
> awk '{ print $50000; }' too_long_line_for_awk.txt
50000

> awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0
```

You could use a tool that is more robust against long lines. You have to decide what the maximum length for the first field is. If we assume 100 then you can try this:

```
cut -b -100 file | awk ...
```

Furthermore (but this is unrelated to your problem) your `awk | grep | awk` construct doesn't make sense. That would be done this way:

```
awk '$1 ~ "/ns/" {sub("^.*/ns/","/ns/",$1); if( !seen[$1]++ ) print $1}' \
  file_name >test1.txt
```

**debug suggestion**

As Ramesh pointed out: It might be interesting to find the line causing the problem. The number of the problem line should be one of those following the number printed (or written to a file) by this command:

```
awk '{ print NR;}' | tail -n 1 >crashline.txt
```

If `awk` empties its buffers before "crashing" then it should be the next number (+1).

Comment: not sure. But will `awk '{       
if (length($1) > 32000)
        print $1;'} filename` help identify the big line?

Comment: grep -o '/ns/.*'    

Gives me only the text that matches the pattern from every line. Which is exactly what I want. Is your awk command doing the same thing? So for example I have something like:

afhdafsdfagasg/ns/importantstuff
asgafhasdfahafdasfdhadf/ns/improtantstuff1
.
.
.

My grep command will return only the /ns/importantstuff from every line.

Comment: @Ramesh No. But `awk '{ print NR;}' | tail -n 1 >crashline.txt` will (maybe not precisely though, due to buffering).

Comment: @HaukeLaging, good suggestion. Probably you can add this as a debug method in the answer too :)

Comment: @JovanAndonov No, it's not. I am still not familiar enough with `-o`... But of course, that's not a reason to use two `awk`s and one `grep`. I have adapted the `awk` command.

Comment: @JovanAndonov The `*` is greedy and since `.` matches everything, you will just get `/ns/everything from first/ns/to the end of the line`.

Comment: I would guess OP is using `mawk` which is a popular default implementation of `awk` on many distributions and does indeed have the 32767 field limit.

Comment: The line causing a problem is cited in the error message : " FNR=117897124 "

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `awk` implement has limit the number of fields.

Example in `mawk`:

`field.c`:

```
/*------- more than 1 fbank needed  ------------*/                              

/*                                                                              
  compute the address of a field with index                                     
  > MAX_SPLIT                                                                   
*/                                                                              

CELL *                                                                          
slow_field_ptr(int i)                                                           
{                                                                               
    ....                                                                   
    if (i > MAX_FIELD)                                                          
        rt_overflow("maximum number of fields", MAX_FIELD);
    ....
}
```

`rt_overflow` (define in `error.c`) is a function to generate error message at run time:

```
/* run time */                                                                  
void                                                                            
rt_overflow(const char *s, unsigned size)                                       
{                                                                               
    errmsg(0, "program limit exceeded: %s size=%u", s, size);                   
    rt_where();                                                                 
    mawk_exit(2);                                                               
}
```

And in file `size.h`:

```
#define  FBANK_SZ    256                                                        
#define  FB_SHIFT      8    /* lg(FBANK_SZ) */                                  
#else                                                                           
#define  FBANK_SZ   1024                                                        
#define  FB_SHIFT     10    /* lg(FBANK_SZ) */                                  
#endif                                                                          
#define  NUM_FBANK   128    /* see MAX_FIELD below */                           

#define  MAX_SPLIT  (FBANK_SZ-1)    /* needs to be divisble by 3 */             
#define  MAX_FIELD  (NUM_FBANK*FBANK_SZ - 1)
```

You can see, `MAX_FIELD` default is `256*128 - 1 = 32767`.

Using `gawk` can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the more specialized a tool is, the better it is at coping with very large files. You could deal with that file in you awk, mind you — you'd just need to extract the first field manually instead of using the built-in field processing. You could combine the grep call and the second awk call into a single awk call, too.

```
awk -F '\n' '
    { sub(/[\t ].*/,"");
      if (match($0, "/ns/")) $0 = substr($0,RSTART); else next; }
    !seen[$0]++
'
```

However, a pipeline through specialized tools is likely to be faster. If your fields always use a tab as the separator, you can use `cut` to isolate the first field. If the separator is a space, make that `cut -d ' '`.

```
cut -f 1 | grep … | …
```

Alternatively, you can use sed for the first two steps. Whether this is faster than `cut … | grep …` depends on your data and on your implementation. In the sed call, replace `\t` by a literal tab character if your implementation doesn't understand `\t`; if your implementation doesn't understand `\n` in an `s` replacement, replace it by backslash-newline.

```
sed -n -e 's/[ \t].*//' \
    -e 's!/ns/!\n&!' -e 'b' \
    -e 's/^.*\n//p'
```

If there is always a single occurrence of `/ns/` in the first field, you can simplify this to the following, which matches the last occurrence of `/ns`:

```
sed -n -e 's/[ \t].*//' -e 's!.*/ns/!/ns/!p'
```

Turning to the last step, if there are a lot of matches, then the awk command will use a lot of memory. If changing the order of the lines in the output is acceptable, you can use `sort -u` instead.

```
cut -f 1 | grep -o '/ns/.*' | sort -u
sed -n -e 's/[ \t].*//' -e 's!.*/ns/!/ns/!p' | sort -u
```